# Choosing appropriate interpoleting points

Tags: real-analysis, interpolation, interpolation-theory

Suppose $f$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ and $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an open interval. Then let $A=\{x\in B:|f(x)|<\epsilon\}$ then can we always choose $d+1$ points $x_i$ from the set $A$ i.e $|f(x_i)|<\epsilon$ such that $|x_i-x_j|\geq\frac{\sigma}{2d}$ for $1\leq i<j\leq d+1$( where $\sigma$ is the Lebesgue measure of the set $A$)

I was initially thinking to take the above points as roots of the polynomial but that doesn't necessarily belong to $B$ and if the roots are same then also it is difficult. Any idea regarding how to choose the points so that it would satisfy the conditions above? Any hints would be very much helpful.

Comment: $B$ could be an interval where the polynomial is far away from $0$. In that case $A$ would be empty, and you could not find any point in it at all, Yes, $\sigma = 0$, but even with that, the statement requires at least one point.

Comment: Sorry yes I should have mentioned. A is nonempty.

Comment: You don't get to pick $A$ other than by controlling $\epsilon$, which makes no difference for the concern. Instead the condition you should have mentioned is that $B$ must contain at least one root of $f$. And *you* should edit your question to add that condition, not expect people to read though the comments to find out what you really meant.

Comment: I suggest trying to solve it first for the case where $B$ contains only one root of $f$, that root is not a turning point, and $\epsilon$ is small enough that no turning point of $f$ is in $A$. I.e. the graph of $f$ on $A$ is nearly a line crossing the $x$-axis, varying only very little from it.

Comment: I have the feeling that the polynomial is mainly irrelevant here. $A$ is a (finite) union of open intervals of total length $\sigma$, and the task is to find $d+1$ points in $A$ with distance $\ge \sigma/(2d)$. That should not be too difficult.